# Why in my manifest add many permission when decode with Advanced ApkTool

Tags: android, android-manifest, decode

In my application I added two permission and then I export to file.apk with my keystore, after I used Advanced ApkTool for decode my apk and when I open manifest it have many new permission in it.
What happened in here?

Comment: What were the permissions that you added and what were the ones that were automatically added?

Comment: post both manifests

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the libraries you added and your minSdkVersion

> If the lower-priority manifest file has a lower value for targetSdkVersion that provides it an implicit permission, and the higher-priority manifest does not have the same implicit permission (because it's targetSdkVersion is equal to or higher than the version in which the restriction was added), then the merger tool explicitly adds the system permission to the merged manifest.

you can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#implicit_system_permissions)